# TextView lost its content when I use the .9.png as a background

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/school_bk"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_above="@+id/nativeg" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/home_tv_schools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="40dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the background picture is a 9.png picture.but my text was dimiss.Is the any wrong with my 9.png or other reasons?

Comment: Try giving the textview the background.

Answer (score 1):

The 9patch drawable contains padding info in it. Try to add android:padding="0dp" to the LinearLayout, if the TextView appears then you set a wrong padding in your 9patch drawable.

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you

android:background="@drawable/bubble"
android:id="@+id/textViewSMS"

android:text="Text"

see this link http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

android:paddingTop="40dip" - seems it's too much.

Comment: Thanks,it is normal whern I use a png picture as background.